# Syntax error when i use ssh with awk over bc

Tags: linux, shell-script, ssh, awk, bc

I basically get the memory usage from two different nodes via ssh and store this in two different variables. I then select the host with lesser memory and return a code 0 or 1.
The array arr contains two hostnames.

```
function selectNode() {
   arr=("$@")

   mem1=$((ssh  ${arr[0]} "free -m | awk 'NR==2{print \"%f\n\", \$3*100/\$2 }'")| bc -l)
   mem2=$((ssh  ${arr[1]} "free -m | awk 'NR==2{print \"%f\n\", \$3*100/\$2 }'")| bc -l)

   if [ "${mem1}" > "${mem2}" ]; then
       node=1
   else
       node=0
   fi


   return $node

}
```

The above script runs properly and returns 0 or 1 but i get a syntax error at the mem1 and mem2 line.

```
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

What is the fix here?

Comment: You don't have to run `awk` and `bc` on the remote system.

Comment: Also note that `>` in `[ ... ]` compares strings alphabetically, and that `bash` doesn't handle floating point arithmetics.

Comment: How do i fix the above line?

Comment: `if (( $(echo "$mem1 > $mem2" | bc -l) == 1 )); then node=1 ...` or `if (( $(expr "$mem1" ">" "$mem2") == 1 )) ...`

Comment: Thanks @glennJackman the second if worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

No need to do calculations using `bc`, you can use

```
mem1=$(ssh  ${arr[0]} "free -m | awk 'END{if(NR==2) print \$3*100/\$2 }'") 
mem2=$(ssh  ${arr[1]} "free -m | awk 'END{if(NR==2) print \$3*100/\$2 }'")
```

Comment: If i use this then the if condition doesn't work.

Comment: I have edited my answer @KiranKumar , for condition to work, you need to use it in END section as `NR` gives **line number** , so if you want to make sure total number of rows should be 2 , you should use END section

Answer (score 0):

You only need to run the `free` command on the servers:

```
selectNode () {
    mem1=$( ssh "$1" free | awk '/^Mem:/ { print int(100*$3/$2) }' )
    mem2=$( ssh "$2" free | awk '/^Mem:/ { print int(100*$3/$2) }' )

    if [ "$mem1" -lt "$mem2" ]; then
        printf '%s\n' "$1"
    else
        printf '%s\n' "$2"
    fi
}
```

Here, only the `free` command is executed on the servers while `awk` is running locally.  Also, we let `awk` convert the result of the calculation to an integer so that we may use it with the `-lt` test later.

You would use this as

```
server=$( selectNode "user@server1" "user@server2" )
```

Alternatively:

```
selectNode () {
    mem1=$( ssh "$1" free | awk '/^Mem:/ { print int(100*$3/$2) }' )
    mem2=$( ssh "$2" free | awk '/^Mem:/ { print int(100*$3/$2) }' )

    [ "$mem1" -lt "$mem2" ]
}
```

and then

```
if selectNode "user@server1" "user@server2"; then
    server="user@server1"
else
    server="user@server2"
fi
```